# What is "baseball’s magic twelve-letter word"?

Tags: baseball, terminology, mlb

What is "baseball’s magic twelve-letter word"?
Columnist Thomas Boswell used this term in his comment "At World Series, a racist taunt fuels a stunning episode of civility" in the following sentence:

> Clearly, at least for a couple of seconds, Gurriel intended to offend Darvish, just as generations of hitters have yelled baseball’s magic twelve-letter word at pitchers after an apparent brushback, followed by a home run.

Source: http://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/at-world-series-a-racist-taunt-fuels-a-stunning-episode-of-civility/2017/10/28/93c5fa9a-bc1b-11e7-9e58-e6288544af98_story.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without wanting to bowdlerise it too much... it starts with "mother" and the next letter is an "f".